# Make body width correspond to divs existence

Tags: html, css

I created a horizontal timeline with dots for each information, however if enough "dots/information" are created the body width needs to be able to expand to make the dots continue on the same line of the timeline instead of moving down a line because of the limited width of the page.

I tried giving the body a larger width, it does fix the problem but I would much rather have the width working dynamically to correspond with the timeline's dots. So if there is only a few dots on the timeline, the page wont have to be any wider, but if there is a lot then the page width should expand.

Here is the css of my timeline. 
The time is implemented with PHP and HTML. The dots are created through a simple php sql loop.

```
 div#timeline3 {
 background-color: lightblue;
 margin-top: 150px;
 height: 12px;
 width: 100%;
        top: 0px;
   position: relative;


      }
 div#timeline3 .inside {
   position: absolute;
   height: 4px;
   background-color: #fff;
   width: 0%;
   top: 3px;
   left: 0;
 }




 div#timeline3 .dot {
   z-index: 99;
   transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
   width: 52px;
   height: 52px;
   border-radius: 50%;
   position: relative;
   top: -20px;
   margin-left: 220px;
   float: left;

   text-align: center;
   cursor: pointer;
   -webkit-box-shadow: 8px 0px 05.3px -8px black, -8px 0px 05.3px -8px black;
    -moz-box-shadow: 8px 0px 05.3px -8px black, -8px 0px 05.3px -8px black;
    box-shadow: 8px 0px 05.3px -8px black, -8px 0px 05.3px -8px black;
 }
 div#timeline3 .dot:nth-child(1) {
   left: 1%;
   background-color: lightblue;

 }
```

Comment: What does your HTML look like?

Comment: My html consist of:
A container div which is the "timeline" class and inside the container is my "dot" class. 

The dots are generated from through a foreach loop using data from my database.